# trying to make subclass but nothing seems to work :(

Tags: python, class, oop

So i'm basicly trying to fetch some data from the duolingo api and make all the different parts accesible via a class (I think that's the best way to make the data accesible in other files?)

I currently have this code:

```
class DuoData:
    def __init__(self, username):
        self.username = username
        self.URL = "https://www.duolingo.com/2017-06-30/users?username={username}"
        self.data = requests.get(self.URL.format(username=self.username))
        self.data_json = self.data.json()

    def get_streak(self):
        return self.data_json['users'][0]['streak']

    class ActiveLanguage:
        def __init__(self, data_json):
            super().__init__()
            self.active_language = data_json['users'][0]['courses'][0]
        
        def get_name(self):
            return self.active_language['title']

        def get_xp(self):
            return self.active_language['xp']
        
        def get_crowns(self):
            return self.active_language['crowns']
```

the get_streak fucntion works perfectly, so

```
duo = DuoData("username")
print(duo.get_streak())
```

prints the streak number like I want, but the following code doesn't work:
`print(duo.ActiveLanguage.get_name())`

I want it so that `duo.ActiveLanguage.getname()` returns the name of the language but it doesn't work like this, I get the following error:
TypeError: DuoData.ActiveLanguage.get_name() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
I already tried lots of different things and this was my best approach but it still doesn't work, can anyone help me? This is my first time working with classes (in Python)
I think maybe subclasses aren't the right approach?

My question is: can i have a class or whatever with a few categories that each have different values?
like: `data.userdata.streak` and `data.userdata.id` and `data.activelanguage.name` and so on?

Comment: That's not how subclasses work.  I'm trying to formulate an answer that shows how to do what you are thinking.

Comment: Thanks man! I'm looking forward to your answer! :)

Comment: `ActiveLanguage` is a *nested* class, not a subclass, and nested classes are rarely used in Python.

Comment: So classes probably aren't the right approach? My question is: can I have an instance or whatever with a few categories that each have a few different values? 
like: `data.userdata.streak` and `data.userdata.id` and `data.activelanguage.name` and so on? where userdata and activelanguage are the 'categories' and streak, id and name are the 'values'?

Comment: @Infinibyte no, that isn't what they are saying. they are saying that you are using *nested classes*, which is *not* the same thing as a subclass. But it *sounds* like you *don't actually want inheritance* but rather, composition. That is, your `DuoData` object should have a `active_language` attribute which is an `ActiveLanguage` object. That is perfectly fine

Answer (score 0):

This is how you would do a subclass.  A subclass means that `ActiveLanguage` is a specific kind of `DuoData`.

However, in this particular case, I'm not sure that's what you want.  It may be you want "encapsulation", where `ActiveLanguage` is a class that stands alone and USES an instance of `DuoData` to do its work.

```
class DuoData:
    def __init__(self, username):
        self.username = username
        self.URL = "https://www.duolingo.com/2017-06-30/users?username={username}"
        self.data = requests.get(self.URL.format(username=self.username))
        self.data_json = self.data.json()

    def get_streak(self):
        return self.data_json['users'][0]['streak']

class ActiveLanguage(DuoData)
    def __init__(self, username):
        super().__init__(username)
        self.active_language = self.data_json['users'][0]['courses'][0]
    
    def get_name(self):
        return self.active_language['title']

    def get_xp(self):
        return self.active_language['xp']
    
    def get_crowns(self):
        return self.active_language['crowns']

duo = DuoData("username")
print(duo.get_streak())
acl = ActiveLanguage("username")
print(acl.get_streak())
print(acl.get_name())
```

Comment: This is indeed what I meant! Thank you very much. I still have one little question: is there a way to make so that I only have to do ClassName("username") once in my main file? So that I can do `data = ClassName("username")` and then use it like `data.DuoData.get_streak()` and `data.ActiveLanguage.get_name()`?

Comment: Look at my second example.  `ActiveLanguage` inherits all the behavior of `DuoData`.  You don't have to create a separate `DuoData` -- just create the `ActiveLanguage`, and now you can call both `get_name` and `get_streak`.  That's the beauty of subclassing.

Comment: Yeah, indeed, now I see it! That seems to work, thank you very much.

Comment: Terminology nitpick, generally when contrasting to inheritance, you would say that this is *composition*, not encapsulation. Both composition and inheritance can help provide encapsulation

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you want a subclass?  If ActiveLanguage is a subclass of DuoData then you are, in effect, saying that ActiveLanguage "is-a" DuoData which does not seem to be your intent.  If your intent is to say that DuoData "has-a" ActiveLanguage attribute then you may want to use composition rather than inheritance:

```
class ActiveLanguage:
    def __init__(self, active_language):
        self.active_language = active_language
    
    def get_name(self):
        return self.active_language['title']

    def get_xp(self):
        return self.active_language['xp']
    
    def get_crowns(self):
        return self.active_language['crowns']

class DuoData:
    def __init__(self, username):
        self.username = username
        self.URL = "https://www.duolingo.com/2017-06-30/users?username={username}"
        self.data = requests.get(self.URL.format(username=self.username))
        self.data_json = self.data.json()

    def get_streak(self):
        return self.data_json['users'][0]['streak']

    def get_active_language(self):
        return ActiveLanguage(self.data_json['users'][0]['courses'][0])


duo = DuoData("username")
print(duo.get_streak())
acl = duo.get_active_language()
print(acl.get_name())
```

Edit: Fixed a cut and paste error by changing:

```
return self.ActiveLanguage(self.data_json['users'][0]['courses'][0])
```

to:

```
return ActiveLanguage(self.data_json['users'][0]['courses'][0])
```

Thanks to @Tim and @Infinibyte for spotting it.

Comment: That's not right.  There is no `self.ActiveLanguage`.

Comment: Indeed, this throws the error:
AttributeError: 'DuoData' object has no attribute 'ActiveLanguage'. Did you mean: 'get_active_language'

Comment: Sorry about that, cut and paste error:
`return self.ActiveLanguage(self.data_json['users'][0]['courses'][0])`
Should have been: `return ActiveLanguage(self.data_json['users'][0]['courses'][0])`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, thanks to Tim and Rhurwitz, I threw your code together and it magically worked! This is the code:

```py
import requests

class DuoData:
    def __init__(self, username):
        self.username = username
        self.URL = "https://www.duolingo.com/2017-06-30/users?username={username}"
        self.data = requests.get(self.URL.format(username=self.username))
        self.data_json = self.data.json()
        self.active = self.ActiveLanguage(self.data_json['users'][0]['courses'][0])

    def get_streak(self):
        return self.data_json['users'][0]['streak']

    class ActiveLanguage:
        def __init__(self, active_language):
            self.active_language = active_language
        
        def get_name(self):
            return self.active_language['title']

        def get_xp(self):
            return self.active_language['xp']
        
        def get_crowns(self):
            return self.active_language['crowns']


duo = DuoData("Infinibyte")
print(duo.get_streak())
print(duo.active.get_name())
print(duo.active.get_xp())
print(duo.active.get_crowns())
```

It works just like I want. However, I do not understand what I did (subclasses, nested classes, ... idk) so any explanation would be welcome ;)